# Changing RELATIVE path to ABSOLUTE path

Tags: .htaccess, relative-path, absolute-path, phpbb

I got these relative links in my phpbb forum which I'd like to replace with absolute links:

For example, in HTML the links are written like:

```
<a href="./viewforum.php?f=5">Bladiebla</a>
<a href="./memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=63">Admin</a>
```

These are links on a domain calld e.g.: http:://www.foo.com

I'd like these links lead to another different domain:

```
http://www.example.org/viewforum.php?f=5
http://www.example.org/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=63
```

Is there any fast way of doing this using htaccess?

The htaccess should **only** account for **/viewforum.php** and **/memberlist.php**

(not site-wide!)

---

The problem is:

I have a forum on a subdomain (forum.example.com) which I scrape and show on the frontpage (example.com). Clicking the links in the scraped forum content however, because they are relative, lead me to places like: example.com/viewforum.php?f=5 (which does not excist) but I'd like them to lead to forum.example.com/viewforum.php?f=5... dunno if I'm clear enough..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No.

I'm almost completely certain that you can't using just `.htaccess`, and if you could, it would be an incredibly messy regular-expression based system that you want to avoid at all costs.

If you must change them, change them manually<sup>1</sup> because if you end up doing it with a `.htaccess` file it will be a complete waste of processing power, too.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Obviously, this doesn't actually have to be completely manual. You can do find and replace stuff - make sure to check the results, though. If the URL will change, then consider outputting it dynamically with PHP instead. Also, just drop the `./` part because it's useless.</sub>

Comment: The problem is:

I have a forum on a subdomain (forum.example.com) which I scrape and show on the frontpage (example.com). Clicking the links in the scraped forum content however, because they are relative, lead me to places like: example.com/viewforum.php?f=5 (which does not excist) but I'd like them to lead to forum.example.com/viewforum.php?f=5... dunno if I'm clear enough..

Comment: @Gerben: Do you scrape them with PHP?

Comment: Yes that's correct, I use simplehtmldom for that and simply output the html.

Comment: @Gerben: So get all the links and replace `./viewforum.php` and `./memberlist.php` with `http://forum.example.com/viewforum.php` and `http://forum.example.com/memberlist.php`, respectively.

Comment: Totally forgot that option, I'll try doing that! Didn't came up to my mind. Accepted your answer, sorry I can't vote up.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use .htaccess file to change the HTML code.

Comment: Hmm I see, can it atleast be redirected?

So pressing:

<a href="./viewforum.php?f=5">Bladiebla</a>

Would lead to:

http://www.example.org/viewforum.php?f=5

Comment: You might be able to redirect, but I don't think you should do that way because one it would be kind of messy and two you are now making an extra redirect which can be easily avoided by changing your HTML code.